# Kotlin: Return generic types from a method?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, jackson

I have the following set of classes:

```
data class ApiResponse<T>(val httpCode: String? = null, val data: T? = null, val status: String? = null, val error: String? = null)

data class Customer(val name: String? = null)

data class User(val userId: String = "", val name: String? = null, val description: String? = null)
```

Basically, I will use the `ApiResponse` class to store an instance of `Customer` or `User` or sometimes a `Map<String, Any?>` in the `data` field generically. With these objects, I wrote this method:

```
private fun handleError(errorJson: String?): ApiResponse<Customer> {
        var response: ApiResponse<Customer>
            try {
                response = objectMapper.readValue(errorJson, object: TypeReference<ApiResponse<Customer>>(){})
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                // unable to parse
                response = ApiResponse(
                        status = "500",
                        error = "Unknown error"
                )
            }
        
        return response
    }
```

Basically, my question is how do I make this method more generic so the same code can be used for both `Customer`,`User`, `Map<String, Any?>` objects? I would know when I am invoking this method the expected return type.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for reified type parameters:

```
private inline fun <reified T> handleError(errorJson: String?): ApiResponse<T> {
        var response: ApiResponse<Customer>
            try {
                response = objectMapper.readValue(errorJson, object: TypeReference<ApiResponse<T>>(){})
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                // unable to parse
                response = ApiResponse(
                        status = "500",
                        error = "Unknown error"
                )
            }
        
        return response
    }
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it looks like the `ObjectMapper` is treating the generic type field(`data`) as `Any` - I always get back a `LinkedHashMap` instead of an instance of the actual class...is there any way around that?